# Error ONLY after adding script in the js file for Importing Objects : Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null ()

Tags: javascript

I searched but could not find the answer.

I have 3 HTML files (index.html, appointment.html, and admin.html), and I have two js files (app.js [using for appointment.html] and admin.js [using for admin.html]).

I have defined many variables, classes and event listeners inside app.js. One of the event listeners (patientsList.addEventListener('click', function(e){ code }) is specific to an element (patientsList) inside appointment.html, while other event listeners are of type (document.addEventListener('click', function(e){ code }).

I added one script file with src="app.js" at the end of the body inside the "appointment.html". There are no issues with the appointment.html file it's dynamics work perfectly.

I added two script files with src="app.js" followed by src="admin.js" at the end of the body inside the "admin.html" since I have to use many of the variables and classes from the app.js file inside the admin.js.

So I am getting all the variables and objects inside the admin.js file but in the logs, I am seeing an error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" for patientsList. Obviously, since there are NO patientsList element inside the admin.html file.

So how would I get rid of this error? I appreciate that you read this long question but it was necessary to explain what's going on. Note I want all the variables and objects of app.js inside admin.js, and I could use document.addEventListener which would not give the error but I tend to avoid this because of processor consumption with every click.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: An easy solution is to split app.js into two different files: common.js, which will contain all the code that is used by both HTML pages, and app.js, which will contain only the code specific to appointment.html. Then you will import import common.js into both pages, app.js into appointment.html and admin.js into admin.html.

Comment: @Unmitigated, I do not think that a minimal reproducible example would be relevant to this question; If I did not misunderstand the OP question, it is just an issue of what cod to put in which JS file and which JS file(s) to insert in which HTML files.

Comment: @secan Thank you so much, you are the savior. You understand my question correctly and that resolved the error. I did not know this tiny concept lol, and wrote a complex code.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transfer variables (data) between 2 pages using vanilla js,

let's say

index.html:
`<button onclick="count()">count</button>`

index1.html:
`<button onclick="count()">count</button>`

app.js:

```js
var counter= 0;

function count(){
  counter++;
}
```

the pages don't share the same counter.

Comment: Nope, you could use all the variables/objects/methods but you have to link that js file in your html file.